# Joomla How to call controller from external script

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I try to launch the functions of a joomla controller from an external script. The beginning of the script works very well but the use of the controller does not. 
Thank you for your help,

```
<?php

define('_JEXEC', 1);    

// this file is in a subfolder 'cron' under the main joomla folder
define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..'));
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

// instantiate application
$app = Factory::getApplication('site');

// database connection
$db = Factory::getDbo();

jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
JLoader::import('Article', JPATH_ROOT . '/components/com_content/controllers');
$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('Article');
var_dump($controller);
```

Comment: In the future, please post your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get anything to instantiate a controller from any other place instead of the controller's component.

So I visit the `BaseController` class where the `getInstance()` method lays. You can hack this by setting a `task` through application input.

```
<?php

define('_JEXEC', 1);

// This file is in a subfolder 'cron' under the main joomla folder
define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..'));
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

// Instantiate application
$app = Factory::getApplication('site');

// Get the input instance
$input = $app->input;

// Database connection
$db = Factory::getDbo();

/**
 * You have to provide a task for getting the controller instance.
 * The `article` is the controller filename as well as the controller class's suffix
 * See the controller class name is `ContentControllerArticle`
 *
 */
$input->set('task', 'article.');

/**
 * The first argument of the getInstance() function is the type.
 * The type is the component name here.
 * And you have to pass the base_path of the component through the $config argument.
 */
$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('Content', ['base_path' => JPATH_ROOT . '/components/com_content']);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($controller);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering me! Your script works fine but it calls the main controller of the component. Is it possible to go down to the controllers folder ?

Comment: I don't get you. Could you please explain it?

Comment: I would like to call a controller from the folder /components/com_content/controllers/xxx.php. In your example, I can call the functions of the main controller here: /components/com_content/controller.php

Comment: If your controller file name is ```xxx.php``` then set the task like ```$input->set('task', 'xxx');``` and leave the other things. And the class name of the ```xxx.php``` file must be ```ContentControllerXxx```.

Comment: But in your example, when I try to do $controller->add() I get this error: "Call to undefined method ContentController::add()" and if I try $controller->display(), I get an error but I manage to call the function.

Comment: The class should be ```ContentControllerArticle::add()``` and you cannot call ```ptotected and private``` functions from the outside of the calss.

Comment: Yes I understand well for the functions and variable in protected or private. But I can't call a public function. Do you have a sample code please, because I can't get out of it... Thank you again for your help !

Comment: I tried this but i got "Class 'ContentControllerArticle' not found"
`$input->set('task', 'article');
$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('Content', ['base_path' => JPATH_ROOT . '/components/com_content']);
print_r(ContentControllerArticle::add());`

Comment: Just use ```print_r($controller->add());``` instead of ```print_r(ContentControllerArticle::add());```

Comment: With `$controller->add()` i've got this message : Call to undefined method ContentController::add(). It's not the good controller ! I tried some stuff without results

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the path where you write the script?

Comment: My script is in /cron/script.php and my controller target is /component/com_content/controllers/articles.php

Comment: Is it ```article(s).php```? IF the file name is ```article(s)``` with an ```s``` then the tast also be ```articles```

Comment: Yes, my bad, it's article.php

Comment: After inspecting the ```BaseController``` I see that they split the task by ```.```, So you have to add a dot after the article. So the code is ```$input->set('task', 'article.');```. And reminds Joomla not to allow anyone to access its controller from outside of a component. It's a hack. So don't hope you can access all of the functions.

Comment: Yesss ! it works fine with the dot !! Thank you very much for helping me ! 
Understand for the hack, i want to call a custom controller by the way ;-)